# What is going on with my nav bar and footer

Tags: html, css

For some reason, my nav bar and footer are messed up. I don't want the user to have to scroll down at all, I want everything to fit on one page. For some reason the footer and the image are screwing that up. The biggest problem though is that my main content is not going in the middle of the page, but rather behind the nav bar.

Here is both CSS and HTML, and my website. Do you guys see any problems?

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway';

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

#page {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

#main {
  width: 1300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  min-height: 90%;
  height: auto;
  height: 89%;
  margin: 0 auto -50px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

#test {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border-top: 10px solid green;
}

header {
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

header img {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  top: 5px;
}

header h2,
a,
a:visited,
a:hover,
a:active {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 105px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #f15a24;
  min-width: 800px;
  text-align: left;
  text-indent: 15%;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #293f6f;
}

#footer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #293f6f;
}

.mycontainer .content {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #293f6f;
  color: #3385FF;
  width: 30px;
}

.mycontainer .title {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  background: #293f6f;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: verdana;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  width: 30px;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: none;
}

nav a {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 12px 25px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: #293f6f;
}

.active {
  background-color: #293f6f;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ry Can Fix It!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
  <link rel="manifest" href="/favicons/manifest.json">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicons/favicon.ico">
  <meta name="msapplication-config" content="/favicons/browserconfig.xml">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="page">
    <header>
      <div>
        <a href="/">
          <img width='15%' style='margin-top: 5px;' src="Logo.png" border=0>
        </a>
      </div>

      <nav>
        <a href="index.html" class='active'>Home</a>
        <a href="#">FAQ's</a>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <div id="main">

      <div class="mycontainer">
        <div class="title">Hey!</div>

        <div class="content">Why?</div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div id="footer">
      <center>
        <img width='10%' src='footerLogo.png'>And why is this logo not moving up?</center>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is this a question or an invitation for peer debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line `overflow:hidden` to the`#main` div

```
#main {
    width: 1300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    min-height: 90%;
    height: auto;
    height: 89%;
    margin: 0 auto -50px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two styles included because of which you are getting this issue:

1.You have set `height:35px;` for **footer**, you are not able to see the footer because of this. so comment `height:35px;`.

2.**nav** has position set to **absolute**. This is not neccessary. Comment it out.